# How to get the returned value in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have 2 functions and I'm trying to get the returned value of other function to continue but the returned value always undefined.

This is my code to return values.

```
export class HomePage {

  variables={
    a:1,
    b:2,
    c:3,
  }

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
     this.function1();
  }

  function1(){
     if(function2()){
        alert("true");
     }else{
        alert("false");
     }
  }

  function2(){
     if(this.variables.a + this.variables.b >= this.variables.c){
        return true;
     }else{
        return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that part of a component? Could you please show us the entire component code?

Comment: @sebaferreras , I saved the editing of my question with my full code

Comment: Thanks, please let me know if the answer solves the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're declaring both functions as part of the component, you need to use the `this` keyword to execute them:

```
 function1(){
     if(this.function2()){ // <--- like this!
        alert("true");
     }else{
        alert("false");
     }
  }
```

Comment: thanks,yes the error solved but the alert always show "false". when I checked console.log(this.function2()); . then its show me "undefined"

Comment: I've created [this demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dEBXpx7z0Na1KpetjubY?p=preview) with exactly the same code (using the `this` keyword for the functions) and seems to be working properly. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I made mistake when I edit my code.. Its work fine.. thank u so much

Comment: Great, glad to hear that :)